# VBA - range.sort script unexpectedly runs other script it shouldn't run

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a workbook and I'm getting an error which is driving me crazy. I really have no idea what's going wrong here.

On the main worksheet (Bestandsübersicht) I have a combobox named ddBestand. On the change event of that combobox it runs a script that checks if certain buttons should be enabled or disabled. The code for this is:

```
Private Sub ddBestand_Change()

    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 3
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Sheets("Bestandsübersicht")

    If ddBestand.Value = "" Then GoTo ExitSub

    Do Until WS.Cells(i, 1).Value = ddBestand.Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If WS.Cells(i, 13).Value = 0 Or _
    Right(Sheets("Bestandsübersicht").Range("AL1").Value, 3) <> "yes" Then
        btnNetwork.Enabled = False
    Else
        btnNetwork.Enabled = True
    End If

    btnChange.Enabled = True
    btnSpecifics.Enabled = True
    btnCopy.Enabled = True

    Exit Sub

ExitSub:
    btnChange.Enabled = False
    btnSpecifics.Enabled = False
    btnNetwork.Enabled = False
    btnCopy.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

This works totally fine when I use ddBestand. But sometimes when I run other scripts this script unexpectedly starts to run, even though those scripts do not relate to eachother. For example, when I run the initialize even for a userform (which is launched from another worksheet) it starts to run at this range.sort method:

```
Sheets("DB_Network").Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Sheets("DB_Network").Range("A2"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

it gives the error 1004 (Unable to set the Enabled propert of the OLEObject class (which is logica, because as we're on another worksheet, the property for those buttons is wrong). As I didn't know how to stop the first script from running, I fixed the script by changing the OLEObjects to this:

```
    Sheets("Bestandsübersicht").OLEObjects("btnChange").Object.Enabled = True
```

Solving the symptoms might not be the prettiest solution, but as I couldn't find out what the problem really was, I decided this was a suitable solution. But it got crazier. I'm still using another version of this document as I need it for my work. Somehow the same sort method started running the same script in the other document, which made the same error occur. Now I really want to solve this problem, as I don't want it to unexpectedly run scripts in other documents. Is there anybody out here who can help? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would guess that your combobox is directly linked to a range. That is not a good idea for precisely this reason. I suggest you use code to populate the control using its List property instead.

Comment: Cool, I've replaced the named range for a AddItem procedure and the problem seems solved now. If you put this info in an answer I can mark this problem as solved. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your combobox is directly linked to a range using the ListFillRange and/or LinkedCell properties. That is not a good idea for precisely this reason. I suggest you use code to populate the control using its `.List` property instead, which is easier and faster than `.AddItem`:

```
Sheets("Bestandsübersicht").OLEObjects("ddBestand").Object.List = Sheets("blah").Range("A2:A100").Value
```

for example.